# Multiple views using one Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I am learning android development, and while making an app i am facing a trouble for which I need suggestion to learn and implement.

I have a layout (layout_view_1) associated with an activity (Activity 1) as in the image below. I have 3 clickable layouts with image and text (button like behavior). On click of these button like layout I want the view to change like shown in layout_view_2. On click of the 3 button like layouts I want to load different screens with changing information (Tab like results).

I can use really tab like thing with Swipe Views / fragment but I want the the look not like tab (with text) with big button like image with text.

So what I did is, create 3 different layouts, make 3 different activities, associate each activity with each layout. On click from the Activity 1 I am launching an intent with the activity class. I get but desired results.

What I want to know is, is there a way to make the same result without creating so many activities? I mean, lo load the layout (result view) of the desired button with the button background changed to selected like effect and switching the buttons to change view. Just like a tabbed window in desktop application.

What I want: On click of each top button open a screen with specific options

What I did: Create multiple activities for each button event using intent

What I don't like: So many activities

What I expect: An idea to show multiple screen for each button events using 1 activity (i.r, Activity 1)

Image of layouts and desired results:

[image: Image of layouts and desired results]

Comment: Not able to understand!!!

Comment: please be clear and show what you tried. so we dont guess answer.

Comment: Sorry if the explanation was not understandable, I have edited. The answers I got doesn't fulfill what i want. Now I think its more clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make three layout in your activity, where two of them are invisible

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

When you click your button hidde the actual layout and display another one :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                   layoutone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   layouttwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}});
```

Comment: you should use "View.GONE" instead of "View.INVISIBLE" because layouts still occupy the space in invisible mode

Comment: Its the whole view not any particular layout in a view.

Comment: Use three LinearLayout.
The first one with the structure of your layout_view_1.
Same for the layout_view_2 and 3.
Then put two of them with visibility gone.

Comment: This is the best solution. Thanks @bastienpinaquy. But this works good only with a Framelayout. Other layouts can't really overlap each other and managing screen are becomes difficult. Works super with FrameLayout. Also I think covering the code with a if statement (if == View.VISIBLE) makes it better.

Answer (score 0):

For tabbed window try to use a [Viewpager](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/training/animation/screen-slide.html) with [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/guide/components/fragments.html) inside.
And if you want style your tabs, just have a look for [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).
Good luck!

Comment: This is a solution I already mentioned, I am looking for any idea without Viepager.